# Inject Javascript into DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am attempting to dynamically inject some js into a DOM element for execution.  However, if I inject at `$(document).ready()`, the script is not evaluated (but injects properly).  Also, if I attempt to inject as the DOM loads, the container element does not, yet, exist.  I have tested by hard-coding the script tags within the container and this works great.  Is there a way to inject js into a DOM element and have it evaluated on DOM ready or as the page loads?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var container = document.getElementById('container_div');
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.appendChild(document.createTextNode('[script]'));
    container.appendChild(script);
    //I've also tried .insertBefore and
    //.parentNode.insertBefore and jQuery's .append()
});
```

Is what I am trying to accomplish possible?

Comment: You don't need a container, and you're already using jQuery. Instead of: `container.appendChild(script);` use: `$('head')append(script);` The issue is: If you can execute THIS script, the page has already loaded.

Comment: The code works for me, except that `'[script]'` throws an error, because `script` is undefined. http://jsfiddle.net/T74Df/

Comment: It injects the script but it is never evaluated.

Comment: What you're doing is the same thing as `eval`, which is `evil`. instead, it's better to reference a script file by setting `script.src = 'path/to/script.js';`.

Comment: In the fiddle I posted, the alert gets executed (chrome), which browser are you using?

Comment: Is it because you're using an anonymous function?  It will not fire if put in $(document).ready().

Comment: What evidence do you have that it isn't evaluated? Does the jsFiddle that @Yoshi gave in the first example work? And how about answering his question about which browser you're using.

Comment: What does this mean: "If you can execute THIS script, the page has already loaded." ? Are you saying that scripts can't be injected after the page is loaded?

Comment: @cliffsofinsanity As I said in my OP, if I hard-code the script tags in the DOM, it works as expected but if I try to inject the tags, it does not.  Yoshi's jsFiddle does work.  I, also, used a test script that I was able to get to fire.  Browser is Safari.  The issue is that I am loading in a script from an external js file to create a variable and populate its attributes.  Then, I am loading in a script from a source (MoPub).  Again, in-line works.  Injection does not.  I dig the user name btw.

Comment: @Joe: Any chance you could give more information, like the `href` you're using to load the script, and perhaps the rest of the actual code you're using? Maybe they have some means of preventing the script from being loaded from external domains.

Comment: @cliffsofinsanity The external js file is from http://ads.mopub.com/js/client/mopub.js.  I can't include any of the other data as it is sensitive but it is simply an adunit, height, and width.

Answer (score 1):

In pure javascript:

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.setAttribute('src','js/myscript.js');
document.body.appendChild(s);
```

This is from [jQuerify](http://www.learningjquery.com/2006/12/jquerify-bookmarklet) I use it to "import" jquery to any page so I can hack on it with firebug, but it should work with any script.